# Calling the same javascript with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript

I'm really new to Javascript and I've been able to make this code work for my project.
https://codepen.io/kevinpowell/pen/EMdjOV

I just need it to work for another button.
So basically another button but able to work calling the same js.

As you can see, current main button is
`<button id="dark-mode-toggle" class="dark-mode-toggle">`

I believe copying the same html button tag and just pasting somewhere else doesn't work. The call will only work for the first button.

Can I somehow create another button with a different class like `.dark-mode-toggle-two` and work that into the js?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to the question itself instead of an external link. You can create a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) if you want to make it runnable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delegate and not use IDs

https://codepen.io/mplungjan/pen/abmmxBd

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let tgt = e.target;
  const possibleParent = tgt.closest("button");
  tgt = possibleParent ? possibleParent : tgt; // clicking button or SVG
  if (tgt.classList.contains("dark-mode-toggle")) { // class='dark-mode-toggle'
    // get their darkMode setting
    darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode');
    // if it not current enabled, enable it
    if (darkMode !== 'enabled') {
      enableDarkMode();
      // if it has been enabled, turn it off  
    } else {
      disableDarkMode();
    }
  }
})
```

Please note that in the codepen, I had to differentiate between dark mode toggles in the section and elsewhere because you have position absolute

Comment: This actually works! Although with your code, the button clicks aren't working when clicking directly on the svg.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm not understanding you correctly, but I am literally clicking on your codepen, and I have to click on the border of the button. Click directly on the centre svg is not doing anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: Accepted! This is my first post and I really appreciate the help! @mplungjan

Comment: You are welcome. Next time try to post a [mcve] here at SO, that would prevent it from being closed. In many cases, external sites change or disappears and is no longer useful for the next person to have the same type of question

Comment: That makes sense. I will keep that in mind. @mplungjan

Comment: @mplungjan Do you think this code has good performance?( I mean about document.addEventListener...)

Comment: @HosseinShourabi the closer to the buttons, the better. So a container around them is preferred. But starting the page with a loop to assign event handlers rivalled buttons is not ideal either. If there are only two buttons then the document level event listener might be overkill

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same function to be called from two different buttons, all you have to do is define the function (instead of using an anonymous function) and then reference it with both event listeners. Something like this:

```js
function myAction() {
  // Do something
}

button1.addEventListener('click', myAction);
button2.addEventListener('click', myAction);
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi I think you can achieve this by using an event listener. Please see the below logic:

JS file

```
function toogleMode(event) {
//your logic
}
```

On your html button you can have something like:

```
<button onclick="toogleMode('$event')">CHange color</button>
```

Comment: Please do not have inline event handlers